# How to set TCP backlog in ASP.NET Kestrel Server

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

ASP.NET Core v2.2.

```
var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(AppConfig.Root);

_host = builder.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.AddServerHeader = false;
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = false;
        options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
        options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
        options.ListenAnyIP(AppConfig.ClientApi.ListeningPort, (listenOptions) =>
        {
            listenOptions.NoDelay = true;
        });
    })
    .UseStartup<ClientApiStartup>()
    .Build();
```

**Question** : How to configure TCP [backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.listen?view=netframework-4.8) for Kestrel Web server?

I am asking this question because clients encounters error occasionally in peak hour when they were trying to connect to my application.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

It only happens in peak hour occasionally (<0.1%), I guess it was because of running out of TCP backlog in accept.

Comment: I'm looking for this problem also right now and found this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because current ASP .NET Core version(v3.0) hardcodes TCP backlog, I solve this by leveraging [Easyhook](https://easyhook.github.io/).

```
class WinsocksHook
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="backlog"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        delegate int ListenDelegate(IntPtr socket, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int backlog);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", EntryPoint = "listen")]
        static extern int Listen(IntPtr socket, uint uType);

        static int SocketListen(IntPtr socket, int backlog)
        {
            return Listen(socket, 2048);
        }

        private static LocalHook _hook;

        public static void Install()
        {
            LoadLibrary("Ws2_32.dll");
            _hook = LocalHook.Create( LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Ws2_32.dll", "listen"), new ListenDelegate(SocketListen), null);
            _hook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new int[] { });
        }
    }
```